# Mathematica List and Which Issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am going crazy because I can't make Mathematica behave..

I am solving an ODE with NDSolve and it does not work because of one function that does not output what I would expect.

My function is of this form:

```
y[x_] := Which[
  0<=x<=10, {{1,2,3},{-9,-8,-7}},
  10<x<20, {{4,5,6},{-6,-5,-4}},
  x>=20, {{7,8,9},{-3,-2,-1}}
];
```

If use the function in a context like this:

```
Ans[x_] := Total[y[x][[1]] {10,20,30}];
```

As long as I call it with a numerical value it works.

```
Ans[3] = Total[y[3][[1]] {10,20,30}] = Total[{1,2,3} {10,20,30}] = Total[{10,40,90}] = 140
```

But when my ODE solver calls it with another function, then it behaves very weird.

```
Ans[z[t]] = Total[y[z[t]][[1]] {10,20,30}] = Total[(0<=x<=10) {10,20,30}] = ??? non-sense
```

It seems that the argument y[z[t]][[1]] simply takes the 'Which' first condition. Why??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `Ans[w] // Trace` to see the evaluation steps Mma goes through to get to the "answer" `60 (0 <= w <= 10)`. You need to pass a numeric argument to your `Ans[..]` function (which `z[t]` is not), so `z[t]/.{t->3}` or `z[3]` would give what you expect. BTW there is a [StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site dedicated to `Mathematica`.

Comment: It still does not work but I have re-explained my problem on the Mma Stack Exchange: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/ndsolve-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question you asked:

The reason is that when you evaluate `y[x]`, it simply gives `Which[0 <= x <= 10, {{1, 2, 3}, {-9, -8, -7}}, 10 < x < 20, {{4, 5, 6}, {-6, -5, -4}}, x >= 20, {{7, 8, 9}, {-3, -2, -1}}]`, the first element of which (retrieved by `[[1]]`) is `0 <= x <= 10`.

---

Some suggestions:

- There's no need for semicolons after `:=` definitions.
- You can use `Piecewise` instead of `Which` in many cases.  `Piecewise` is a mathematical construct while `Which` is a programming one.
- When you need a function that should only evaluate for numerical arguments, but not for symbolic ones, then use

  ```
  Clear[ans]
  ans[x_?NumericQ] := Total[y[x][[1]] {10,20,30}]
  ```